# Can this property of certain pythagorean triples in relation to their inner circle be generalized for other values of $n$?

Tags: geometry, triangles, pythagorean-triples

This question was raised in comments of

[Is the $(3,4,5)$ triangle the only rectangular triangle with this property?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488978/)

and I was suggested to ask it as a separate one.

First some notation, let's write $(a,b,c)$ where $a<=b<c$ for a pythagorean triple, and let's write $(x,y,z)$ where $x<=y<z$ for the distances from the vertices to the center of the inner circle of the corresponding right triangle.

[image: a b c and x y z]

($XYZ$ should be lowercase but geogebra did not allow these labels)

The answer to above question proved (partially left to reader) the property:

$x * y = z$ if and only if $c - b = 1$

In comments was asked if a similar property would exist for $c - b = 2$

and it was confirmed (and proof was left to reader) that:

$x * y = 2 * z$ if and only if $c - b = 2$

Somewhat natural question then was raised (by me) if one can generalize for other values of $n >= 1$, that is:

for which $n$ (perhaps all) holds:

$x * y = n * z$ if and only if $c - b = n$

?

Thanks to @heropup for the suggestion (and the answers for $n=1,2$)

**update**

A simple computer programmed enumeration seems to confirm equivalence. At least for all $(a,b,c)$ with maximum $c <= 10000$. Note that it is not known to me (but perhaps it is known to others) if all $c - b$ cover all $n >= 1$.

So asking for all $n$ is a bit ambiguous since some $n$ might never occur.

An alternative, perhaps better, question rephrase is:

Prove equality

$$x * y = (c - b) * z$$

for all pythagorean triples.

**update** see also my answer below for non pythagorean triples

Comment: Just curious : are these properties 'well known'? If well known, perhaps a self contained proof (perhaps using other 'well known' properties with self contained proofs recursively) exists somewhere? I personally still fail to bridge the required gaps kindly offered as exercise by the experts who answered.

Comment: Primitive triples have $\{a,b\}=\{2mn,m^2-n^2\}$, $c=m^2+n^2$ where $m,n$ are of different parity and $m>n>0$. If $m^2-n^2<2mn$, then $c-b=m^2+n^2-2mn=(m-n)^2$ is the square of an odd number; if $2mn<m^2-n^2$, then $c-b=2n^2$ is twice a square; so the only possibilities for $c-b$ are $1,2,8,9,18,25,32,49,50,\dots$. If we allow nonprimitive triples, then of course every value for $c-b$ is possible; to get $c-b=t$, just use the triple $(a,b,c)=(3t,4t,5t)$.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291310/the-distance-from-the-incenter-to-an-acute-vertex-of-a-right-triangle

Comment: should I promote this as a hidden pearl? see my answer ....

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but, be my guest.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : now that you read my answer and refined it, be my guest to up or down vote it or, better, leave it as is : hidden :-)

Comment: I'm trying to support the moderators strike by not doing any voting (or editing, or other moderation activities).

Comment: You are a good man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a,b,c)$ be a primitive Pythagorean triple with $a<b<c$. Then $\{a,b\}=\{2mn,m^2-n^2\}$ and $c=m^2+n^2$ for some coprime integers $m>n>0$ of different parity. If $2mn<m^2-n^2$, then $c-b=2n^2$ is twice a square. Moreover, if $m>3n$, then $2mn<(2/3)m^2<(8/9)m^2<m^2-n^2$, so for every $n$ there exists $(a,b,c)$ such that $c-b=2n^2$.

If $m^2-n^2<2mn$, then $c-b=(m-n)^2$, the square of an odd number. Let $k\ge7$ be odd, let $m=2k-2$, $n=k-2$; then $m,n$ are coprime of different parity, $m>n>0$, and $m-n=k$; also, $m^2-n^2=3k^2-4k$, $2mn=4k^2-12k+8$, and $m^2-n^2<2mn$ is equivalent to $k^2-8k+8>0$, which is $(k-4)^2>8$, which is true for $k\ge7$. So, for every odd $k\ge7$ there exists $(a,b,c)$ such that $c-b=k^2$. For $k=1,3,5$, respectively, we can take $(a,b,c)$ to be $(3,4,5)$, $(33,56,65)$, $(65,72,97)$ to get $c-b=k^2$.

Conclusion: for a primitive Pythagorean triple, $c-b$ can take on every odd square, and every twice-a-square, and only those values.

Given any positive integer $t$, the Pythagorean triple $(3t,4t,5t)$ has $c-b=t$, so, if non-primitive triples are allowed, then $c-b$ can take on any positive integer value.

Now, let's bring in $x,y,z$. Using the formulas at [The distance from the incenter to an acute vertex of a right triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291310/the-distance-from-the-incenter-to-an-acute-vertex-of-a-right-triangle), we have
$2x^2=(a+b-c)^2$
$2y^2=a^2+(c-b)^2$
$2z^2=b^2+(c-a)^2$
If $a=2mn<m^2-n^2=b$, $c=m^2+n^2$, then
$$
4(xy)^2=(2mn-2n^2)^2(4m^2n^2+4n^4)=(4n^2)(m-n)^2(4n^2)(m^2+n^2)=16n^4(m-n)^2(m^2+n^2)
$$
so $xy=2n^2(m-n)\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$, and
$$
2z^2=(m^2-n^2)^2+(m-n)^4=2m^4-4m^3n+4m^2n^2-4mn^3+2n^4=2(m-n)^2(m^2+n^2)
$$
so $z=(m-n)\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$. Thus, $xy=2n^2z=(c-b)z$, as requested.

If $a=m^2-n^2<2mn=b$, $c=m^2+n^2$, then
$$
4(xy)^2=(2mn-2n^2)^2((m^2-n^2)^2+(m-n)^4)=8n^2(m-n)^4(m^2+n^2)
$$
so $xy=\sqrt2n(m-n)^2\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$, and
$$
2z^2=4m^2n^2+4n^4=4n^2(m^2+n^2)
$$
so $z=\sqrt2n\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$. Thus, $xy=(m-n)^2z=(c-b)z$, again as requested.

If the triple is not primitive, the common factor cancels out in the end, and the conclusion remains.

Comment: Thanks for this easy (for me) to follow and complete proof! Was this a known (to you) or well known property?

Comment: No. All I knew was the $2mn,m^2-n^2,m^2+n^2$ parametrization of Pythagorean triples, the rest I worked out or, in the case of the formulas for the distance from a vertex to the incenter, searched for on the web.

Comment: Big thanks and congratulations. I am happy to hear this is not so common knowledge which I rather incidentally found.

Comment: @FirstName LastName  
Yesterday, my reputation dropped $15$ points, because one of my answers to this question was no longer marked as correct. Did I do something to warrant this? Please let me know. I’m hoping that my answer with the drawings might be correct if the other was not.

Comment: @poetasis : I am really sad the forum algorithm works the way it does ... I have consistently up-voted anything you wrote. But there seems to be only one answer one can accept. I would not mind accepting two. This time I chose to accept the one I understood best. But that's not fair: my weakness drops your reputation. It should be the other way around. Would it help if I start a 100 reputation bounty? Can someone else then transfer it to you? Or do I have to do it?

Comment: @FirstName LastName  Starting a bounty would cost you reputation for no good reason.  I can manage without it. Glad I could help and it was a fascinating problem to solve.

Comment: @poetasis I appreciate your kindness and admire your expertise

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For all primitive Pythagorean triples (right triangles with integer sides),
$\space C-B=(2n-1)^2,n\in\mathbb{N}$

This can be seen at a glance using a formula I developed in $2009.$

\begin{align*}
&A=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k\\
&B=               &&2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\
&C=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k+2k^2
 \end{align*}

This formula generates all triples where $\space GCD(A,B,C)\space$ is an odd square. This includes all primitives where $GCD(A,B,C)=1.$

For Pythagorean triples, it appears that
$\quad z^2=(2n-1)^2C$

Comment: Sorry for late reaction. I probably misunderstand, and, also, I am not expert at all of Pythagorean triples. Are you telling us you have a proof for the general case of any $n$? Also: $C-B$ does not need to be a square, does it? What about $(8,15,17)$ where $C-B=2$. I am sure I missed a point here and I apologise.

Comment: @FirstName LastName $\qquad$ Do not use $(8,15,17).\quad$ In primitive triples, half have $B>A$ like $\space(3,4,5), (5,12,13)\space$ and half have $A>B$ like $\space(15,8,17), (33,12,37).\quad$ We can see that 
$\space 5-4=13-12=1,\space$ $\space 17-8=9,\space$ and $\space37-12=25,\space$ and that $C-B$ is an odd square.  For proof, start playing around with algebra using the functions of my formula for sides.

Comment: OK: On Wikipedia I read about this $B>A$ versus $A<B$ exchange related to Euclid's formula to generate all primitive ones. As for the proof ... I am afraid I might leave the honor to you :-)

Comment: @FirstName LastName Euclid's formula reverses the order of $A$ and $B$ when generating imprimitive triples; mine does not. I developed my formula without even knowing that Euclid’s formula exists. Later I found that Euclid’s formula generates the same triples as mine if you let.
\begin{align*}
A= &(2n-1+k)^2-k^2\\
B=2&(2n-1+k)k\\
C=&(2n-1+k)^2+k^2
\end{align*}

It will take me time to work on a proof but I will try.

Comment: Sorry for asking: I want to understand it appears that $z^2=(2n-1)^2C$. So $z^2/C$ is always a square, but, for Pythagorean triple $(3,4,5)$, $z^2=10$ and $C=5$, so, $z^2/C=2$ is not a square. I must be missing something and I apologize again.

Comment: @FirstName LastName Perhaps I got sloppy with my math or it only works for $n>1$. It will take me time to check because I have very limited time available for MSE.

Comment: We may need to move discussion to chat, but, @poetasis, do you happen to know if **all** positive natural numbers $n$ occur as $n=c-b$  when going over **all** primitive pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ where $a<=b<c$?

Comment: @FirstName LastName For primitives, $C-B$ is never an even number. It is always an odd square: $(2n-1)^2.\quad$ Also, $A$ and $B$ are never equal because they are of opposite parity, and $A>B$ in half of all triples.

Comment: I agree since your $A$ and $B$ definitions switch place 'automagically' ... and yes : $a$ is never $b$ (I am sorry for that error) ... I intentionally write **lowercase** for $a<b<c$. But then $c-b$ must not be odd, like in  $(a,b,c)=(8,15,17)$, $c-b=2$  is even.

Comment: @FirstName LastName Your example of $(15,8,17)$ has $C-A=2$ and 
$C-B=9=3^2=\big(2(2)-1\big)^2=(2n-1)^2.$ You seem to keep confusing A and B. For simplicity, try to remember that A is always odd.

Comment: Please refer to OP which is about e.g. $c-b$ for $(a,b,c)=(8,15,17)$, which, for $(A,B,C)=(15,8,17)$ is $C-A$ indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion before comes from not ensuring which of $A$ and $B$ is used in calculations. For example, you thought
$\space z^2=10\space$ for $\space (3,4,5)\space$ when the calculations below show that
$\space y^2=10,\space$ and $\space z^2=5.\quad$  We begin with *my* formula for generating Pythagorean triples.

\begin{align*}
&A=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k\\
&B=               &&2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\
&C=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k+2k^2
 \end{align*}

Let $\space A\space$ be the horizontal component and let $\space B\space$ be the vertical component.

\begin{align*}
x^2&=r^2+r^2\\
y^2&=(B-r)^2+r^2\\
z^2&=(A-r)^2+r^2\\
\end{align*}

From these equations comes the following table.
[image]

By studying these figures we can see numerous relationships such as $\space x^2=2r^2,\space$ and some are unexpected such as how $\space r=(2n-1)k,\quad$ how $\space \dfrac{y^2}{C}=2k^2\,\quad$ and how
$\space\dfrac{z^2}{C}=(2n-1)^2.\quad$ Algebraic manipulation of these functions should be able to provide a proof but the visual here is satisfying, even without it.

Comment: You are right, I will change picture to reduce confusion (note geogebra did not allow me to use lowercase x y z so I used uppercase).

Comment: @FirstName LastName I see nothing wrong with the picture, BTW, is this answer correct for your OP question?

Comment: Proof of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488978 also left some exercise to the reader and I ticked it as answer, so I want to be fair and will tick yours, which also leaves some  exercise to the reader as well. But, for both questions I am not able as reader to complete the exercise ... but then, I am not all that skilled :-) which is why I ask ...

Comment: @FirstName LastName I’ll see what I can do algebraically now that we know the line length relationships

Answer (score 1):

To show some of the more unexpected relationships, we begin with the formula
\begin{align*}
&A=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k\\
&B=               &&2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\
&C=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k+2k^2
 \end{align*}
Observation:$\quad \text{inradius}=r=(2n -1)k$

Proof: We let inradius(r)=area(a)/semiperimeter(s)
and we let $j=(2n-1)$

$a=\dfrac{AB}{2}
=\dfrac{(j^2+2jk)(2jk+2k^2)}{2}\\
\quad=jk(j^2+3jk+2k^2)$

$s=\dfrac{A+B+C}{2}
=\dfrac{(j^2+2jk)+(2jk+2k^2)+(j^2+2jk+2k^2)}{2}\\
\quad =j^2+3jk+2k^2$

$r=\dfrac{a}{s}
=\dfrac{jk(j^2+3jk+2k^2)}{(j^2+3jk+2k^2)}=jk
=(2n-1)k$

Observation: $\quad x^2=2(2n-1)^2k^2$

Proof:$\quad x^2=r^2+r^2=2r^2=2(2n-1)^2k^2$

Observation: $\quad y^2=2k^2C$

Proof:
\begin{equation}
\quad y^2=r^2+(B-r)^2
=j^2k^2 +(2jk+2k^2\space  - \space jk)^2\\
=2 j^2 k^2 + 4 j k^3 + 4 k^4\\
=2k^2(j^2+ 2 j k + 2 k^2)\\
=2k^2C
\end{equation}

Observation: $\quad z^2=(2n-1)^2C$

Proof:
\begin{equation}
\quad z^2=r^2+(A-r)^2
=j^2k^2 +       (j^2 +2jk\space  - \space jk)^2\\
=j^4 + 2 j^3 k + 2 j^2 k^2\\
=j^2(j^2+ 2 j k + 2 k^2)\\
=(2n-1)^2C
\end{equation}
[image]

[image]

$\textbf{Update:}$
$$\text{Given:}\quad x^2=2 j^2 k^2\quad y^2=2k^2C\quad z^2=j^2C$$

\begin{align*} \dfrac{x^2y^2}{z^2}
&=\dfrac{(2 j^2 k^2) (2 k^2 C)}{j^2C}=4k^4\\
\therefore\quad x^2y^2&=4k^4z^2\implies xy=2k^2z
\end{align*}

Do keep in mind that side A and side C are always odd and that side B is always even as shown in this table of elements generated by the formula above. Also note how, in row$1,\space C-B=1\space$ and in column$1,\space C-A=2.$ To generalize, as can be seen by glancing at the formula,
$\space C-A=2k^2\space$ and $\space C-B=(2n-1)^2.\quad$

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61  \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89  \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169 \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Comment: Thanks for your expert follow up ... I have encountered other surprising relationships too and, for now, for proof, I focus rather on geometric (using complex plane) arguments (inspired by a 3blue1brown video) more than on algebraic ones, which always seem to get, at least me, into a tunnel or dead-end. But even geometric animations onto a grid do not seem to provide me a clue

Comment: @FirstName LastName 
What other relationships would you like to prove? BTW

$\text{circumradius}(c)=\dfrac{product}{4*area}
=\dfrac{ABC}{4\bigg(\dfrac{AB}{2}\bigg)}=\dfrac{ABC}{2AB}
=\dfrac{C}{2}$

Comment: You derived nice formulas for $x^2$ $y^2$ $z^2$ ... do they prove $x*y=(c-b)*z$ ? I think so provided $(c-b)=2k$ ... is it? Sorry if I miscalculated.

Comment: I dis miscalculate. I now think $\frac{x*y}{z}=2*k^2$ ... so $(c-b)$ must be $2*k^2$ which, for example, would not match case $c-b==1$ or would it somehow?

Comment: @FirstName LastName 
I have updated my answer to show
$xy=2k^2z.$ I am concerned, however, that you may still sometimes mistake which side is A and which side is B. See the note in my update.

Comment: For triple (3,4,5) and k=1 in the table top left corner $xy=2k^2z$ would mean $xy=2z$, but, $x=\sqrt{2}$, $y=\sqrt{5}$ and $z=\sqrt{10}$ so it rather seems $xy=z<2z$ ... I am indeed confused but however prepared to rest my case :-)

Comment: @FirstName LastName $\quad \text{for }\space(3,4,5),\space  x=\sqrt{2}\quad y=\sqrt{10}\quad z=\sqrt{5}$

$$xy=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{10}=\sqrt{20}=2\sqrt{5}=2z$$

Comment: But OP required $y<z$ ... in any case @poetasis ... I am 100% **sure** you are right and I am wrong being not in any way expert. Thanks for your kind and patient follow up! The good news is : conjecture proven by you.

Comment: @FirstName LastName 
$\quad y>z\space$ because $A=3,\space B=4.\quad$ I repeat that you must keep track of what is the horizontal and what is the vertical component of the triples.
$\quad A<B\implies z<y.$

Comment: @FirstName LastName 
  I added a drawing to my answer so you can see, with A being horizontal, and B being vertical, why z is smaller than y for a 3,4,5 triangle. For triangles where $A>B$, like $(15,8,17)$, line-z would be the longest.

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, I found a bit more general evidence.

I leave some details as exercise but, one finds and has

$y^2=c(c-b)$

and

$z^2=c(c-a)$

so

$y^2=z^2(c-b)/(c-a)$

Call $r$ radius of inscribed circle, then, one finds and has

$r=(a+b-c)/2$

and

$x^2=2r^2$

So one further calculates (by squaring $r$)

$x^2=(c-a)(c-b)$

But then

$x^2y^2=(c-a)(c-b)z^2(c-b)/(c-a)=z^2(c-b)^2=z^2n^2$

So eventually

$xy=(c-b)z=nz$

This holds for **any** rectangular triangle. It just so happens that for pythagorean triples n is a natural number making it look a bit more appealing :-).

So for example (no natural pythagorean triple) with

$a=1$

$b=2$

$c=\sqrt 5$

**geogebra** tells me (up to only 4 decimals as limited check)

```
x=0.5402

y=0.7265

z=1.6625
```

**julia** tells me

```
julia> a=1
1

julia> b=2
2

julia> c=sqrt(a^2+b^2)
2.23606797749979

julia> sqrt(5)
2.23606797749979

julia> x=0.5402
0.5402

julia> y=0.7265
0.7265

julia> z=1.6625
1.6625

julia> sqrt(c*(c-b))
0.726542528005361

julia> sqrt(c*(c-a))
1.6625077511098139

julia> c-b
0.2360679774997898

julia> x*y
0.3924553

julia> (c-b)*z
0.39246301259340055
```

So that seems to confirm (up to limited amount of decimals).

Comment: I should perhaps stay humble and quiet, but, the fact that, perhaps misleadingly, the formula has nothing to do with pythagorean triples, surprised me and I wanted to share it with others as a generic geometric one.

Comment: Nice. Filling in a few details, $2x^2=(a+b-c)^2=a^2+2a(b-c)+(b-c)^2=c^2-b^2+2a(b-c)+(b-c)^2$ $=(c-b)(c+b-2a-b+c)=2(c-b)(c-a)$ so $x^2=(c-b)(c-a)$, and $2y^2=a^2+(c-b)^2=c^2-b^2+(c-b)^2=(c-b)(c+b+c-b)=2c(c-b)$ so $y^2=c(c-b)$, and $2z^2=b^2+(c-a)^2=c^2-a^2+(c-a)^2=(c-a)(c+a+c-a)=2c(c-a)$, so $z^2=c(c-a)$. Then $x^2y^2=(c-b)^2c(c-a)=(c-b)^2z^2$, so $xy=(c-b)z$.

Comment: thanks for appreciation and filling in the details. not sure if this is a well known equation...